# Windows phone 7 doesn't execute jquery document.ready using phonegap

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, cordova

Using windows phone 7 emulator and cordova 2.4.0

when i navigate from page A to page B using

```
window.location.replace("B.html")
```

the

```
$(document).ready(function () {}) in B.html didn't execute...
```

I've tried the same code on an onclick event binder in a dummy button and it worked

I think their is some issue between windows phone 7 and jquery document.ready event, Any one have any idea the reason behind and how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not rely on document.ready while doing PhoneGap. You should use the deviceready event of PhoneGap. 
Please see these threads: [javascript document.ready() function not working in windows phone emulator with cordova 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860635/javascript-document-ready-function-not-working-in-windows-phone-emulaiton-with)

[JQuery document.ready vs Phonegap deviceready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576062/jquery-document-ready-vs-phonegap-deviceready)